# App is logging out on restart using GetX state management. Sign in normally but when restated the app looses its state

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

I am very new to Dart, and coding in general. I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part, I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, yet I cannot figure out my most recent errors. I made a simple app using GetX and firebase. The app logs in but when I do a restart app logs out. my objective is the user must stay on HomePage() until he is not logged out. On logout the app should go to LandingPage

Here is my auth controller:-

```
import 'package:definer_lms/views/views.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
 static AuthController instance = Get.find();
 late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
 void onReady() {
 super.onReady();
 _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
 _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
 ever(_user, _initialScreen);
 }

 _initialScreen(User? user) {
 if (user == null) {
  print("loging Page");
  Get.offAll(() => const LandingPage());
  } else {
  Get.offAll(() => const HomePage());
  }
  }

   void signup(String email, password) async {
  try {
  await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  } catch (e) {
  Get.snackbar(
    "About User",
    "User Message",
    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
    titleText: const Text(
      "Account creation failed",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    messageText: Text(
      e.toString(),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    );
    }
    }

    void signIn(String email, password) async {
  try {
   await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
   } catch (e) {
    Get.snackbar(
    "About Login",
    "Login Message",
    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
    titleText: const Text(
      "Account login failed",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    messageText: Text(
      e.toString(),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    );
   }
   }

 void logOut() async {
 await auth.signOut();
 }
 }
```

Splash Screen

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:definer_lms/views/views.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
_SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
 }

 class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
 @override
void initState() {
Timer(
    Duration(seconds: 3),
    () => {
          Get.off(LandingPage(), transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade)
        });

  super.initState();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2AA8A1),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: Image.asset('images/dlw.png'),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff2AA8A1),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

My Landing Page:-

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'views.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
 _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {



 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(

  body: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Image.asset('images/definerLogo.gif'),
      ),
    ),

  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: (){
            print('Bottom Button Pressed');

          },
          child: Text('Browse', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade300, fontSize: 20.0),),
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Get.to(SignIn());

          },
          child: Text('Sign In', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade300, fontSize: 20.0),),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

My Home Page

```
import 'package:definer_lms/controllers/authController.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=> AuthController.instance.logOut(), child: Text('Logout'))

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Run Message While Login:

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /SignIn
I/FirebaseAuth( 6676): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to 
fallback implementation
W/System  ( 6676): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 6676): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 6676): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 
lpbfNUpaEIQ9s38FtWmaGTfmFjo1 ).
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /HomePage
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /SignIn
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /LandingPage
```

Run message after restarting App

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 932ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 6676): Local module descriptor class for 
com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6676): Considering local module 
com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module 
com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6676): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6676): Failed to report request stats: 
com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class 
android.content.Context, long, long]
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 6676): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE 
message
[GETX] Instance "AuthController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "AuthController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /HomePage
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /
W/libc    ( 6676): calloc(434055556, 1) failed: returning null pointer

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image frame:
Exception: Codec failed to produce an image, possibly due to invalid image data.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/dlw.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#55b5e(), name: "images/dlw.png", scale: 1.0)



=============================================================================
[GETX] WARNING, consider using: "Get.off(() => Page())" instead of "Get.off(Page())".
Using a widget function instead of a widget fully guarantees that the widget and its 
controllers will be removed from memory when they are no longer used.
  
[GETX] REPLACE ROUTE /HomePage
[GETX] NEW ROUTE /LandingPage
```

Can anyone Help

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your AuthController extends from `GetxController` to `GetxService`.

And declare the AuthController on the main.dart:

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp();

 await Get.putAsync<AuthController>(
      () async => AuthController());
```

`GetxService` unlike `GetxController`, does not automatically dispose when you dispose a page or when `Get.delete()` is used. Thats why it's commonly used for Auth control as an example.